# How do different secret-key algorithms generate the same data?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hash, java

How do different secret-key algorithms generate the same data?

In the snippet below, I use `PBEWithMD5AndDES` to produce one key, and `PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256` to produce another key, but with the same password. How is backwards compatibility preserved between algorithms, but they are somehow also harder to reverse engineer / more secure?

```
        KeySpec keySpec1 = new PBEKeySpec("test".toCharArray());
        SecretKey key1 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").
                generateSecret(keySpec1);
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key1.getEncoded())); // Prints dGVzdA==

        KeySpec keySpec2 = new PBEKeySpec("test".toCharArray());
        SecretKey key2 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256").
                generateSecret(keySpec2);
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key2.getEncoded()));  // Prints dGVzdA== also!
```

Comment: They don't. I'm not sure what is going on with your code, but the output you are getting is the base64 encoding of 'test', i.e. it is just outputting an encoded version of the plaintext password, not the derived keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## They don't. Your code is wrong.

If you Base64-decode `dGVzdA==`, you will see the output is `test`.

Your code just encodes the string `test` as base64, then prints it. If you look at your code, you first define `test` to be the key material, then you generate a `SecretKey` object from it and finally encode that. No encryption is actually happening.

Comment: Thanks! I thought `generateSecret` would actually do the encryption.

Comment: @keian No, it merely generated a secret key object. The fact that you didn't specify any data to be encrypted could have been a hint as well ;)